# Angular.js: my template is in $templateCache, but won't be loaded - 404

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have an AngularJS project packed into a bundle with Webpack. I packed tempaltes into the bundle with ng-template-loader and html-webpack-loader.

Now I'm running it in webpack-dev-server and when I visit `/home` page, which needs `components/home/home.html` template, the browser fails with:

`GET http://localhost:8001/components/home/home.html 404 (Not Found)`

But when I look into the webpack bundle, everything seems fine:

```
    function routes($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            // parent: "application-layout",
            templateUrl: __webpack_require__(20), //templateUrl.html,
            controller: "HomeController"
        });
    }

    exports.default = _angular2.default.module("home", []).controller('HomeController', HomeController).config(routes);

/***/ },
/* 20 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    var path = '/components/home/home.html';
    var html = "<!-- Header -->\n<div id=\"header\" ng-include=\"'components/header/header.html'\"></div>\n\n<!-- Navigation -->\n<aside id=\"menu\" ng-include=\"'components/navigation/navigation.html'\"></aside>\n\n<!-- Main Wrapper -->\n<div id=\"wrapper\">\n \n    Custom content will go here.\n \n    <!-- Right sidebar -->\n    <div id=\"right-sidebar\" ng-include=\"'components/right_sidebar/right_sidebar.html'\" class=\"sidebar-open\" ng-show=\"rightSidebar\"></div>\n \n    <!-- Footer -->\n    <footer class=\"footer\" ng-include=\"'components/footer/footer.html'\"></footer>\n \n</div>";
    window.angular.module('ng').run(['$templateCache', function(c) { c.put(path, html) }]);
    module.exports = path;
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that module `20` is not defined as Angular module but is required from `config` block.

Once bootstrapping process has started, new items can't be added to Angular modules, calls to module methods (`angular.module('ng').run` in this example) will be ignored.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to fix this? It's an absolutely standard webpack build, I didn't touch anything. Been scratching my head for the whole day %(

Comment: You haven't posted the source code for your bundle, but I guess that you do [this](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader#beware-of-requiring-from-the-directive-definition), while ng-template-loader  expects you do do [that](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader#usage), exactly for the reason explained above.